# How to create an extension method in TypeScript for 'Date' data type

Tags: typescript, extension-methods

I have tried to create an extension method in TypeScript based on this discussion (*https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9*), but I couldn't create a working one.

Here is my code,

```
namespace Mynamespace {
    interface Date {
        ConvertToDateFromTS(msg: string): Date;
    }

    Date.ConvertToDateFromTS(msg: string): Date {
        //conversion code here
    }

    export class MyClass {}
}
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to change the prototype:

```
interface Date {
    ConvertToDateFromTS(msg: string): Date;
}

Date.prototype.ConvertToDateFromTS = function(msg: string): Date {
    // implement logic
}

let oldDate = new Date();
let newDate = oldDate.ConvertToDateFromTS(TS_VALUE);
```

Though it looks like you want to have a static factory method on the `Date` object, in which case you better do something like:

```
interface DateConstructor {
    ConvertToDateFromTS(msg: string): Date;
}

Date.ConvertToDateFromTS = function(msg: string): Date {
    // implement logic
}

let newDate = Date.ConvertToDateFromTS(TS_VALUE);
```

Comment: throwing error, 1. property  ConvertToDateFromTS is does not exist on type DateConstructor 2.property   ConvertToDateFromTS is does not exist on type Date

Comment: Where are you getting these errors? It works for me: [code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20DateConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ConvertToDateFromTS(msg%3A%20string)%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ADate.ConvertToDateFromTS%20%3D%20function(msg%3A%20string)%3A%20Date%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Date%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ConvertToDateFromTS(msg%3A%20string)%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ADate.prototype.ConvertToDateFromTS%20%3D%20function(msg%3A%20string)%3A%20Date%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Does this have to be in the same file as the original definition of the type? Also, it didn't like this when I tried to use generics. Otherwise, great answer. Just a caveat for others (unless those can be clarified)

Comment: @vbullinger No, You can add to a prototype of an object which is defined elsewhere, in this example, `Date` is a built-in type, so it was defined somewhere else. As for generics, what exactly did you try do to?

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but I think I wanted to extend Promise<T>. I did something else instead.

Comment: @vbullinger It works to do the same thing with `Promise<T>`. If you can come up with an example then I'll be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I went a different route and I'm happy with it, so I don't need to reinvent the solution.

Comment: this seems to work for existing types but not custom types

Comment: @DaveCousineau the question and answer are both about existing types, you don't need this for custom types.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I have auto-generated typescript classes that I would like to manually add more things to. So far support for partial classes is refused. There must be a way to do it like this, but it doesn't seem to work. I may have to resort to having my own system that concats source files together or something.

Comment: @DaveCousineau there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to augment your auto generated classes. i suggest that you post a new question describing your specific case.

Comment: For `Date`, you need to enclose the interface in `declare global {  }` code block. Otherwise, the call to the prototype won't find the new method.

Comment: How to place extension method and usage in separated files?

Comment: what is TS_VALUE?

Comment: I added an `import` in the file and then it does not work. How to add an import?

Answer (score 14):

The previous answer gave Typescript errors

Found this to work great!

```
export {}

declare global {
   interface Date {
      addDays(days: number): Date;
   }
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function (days: number): Date {
   if (!days) return this;
   let date = this;
   date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

   return date;
};
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/weslleih/b6e7628416a052963349494747aed659)

Comment: If you need to use this from Angular, then put the import statement in to the app.module.ts to make the extension available globally, and do it for the whole file, e.g. import 'path/to/my/file'