# javascript extending Array and gain full control

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

what I'm trying to accomplish is , a `sub/child` `class` of `Array<T>` , that has my own custom methods , but am facing a problem here , I can't edit the items within the `Array` ...

lets see an example to clarify what I'm doing:

```
export class Collection<T> extends Array<T>
{
    remove(key, value) {
        this = this.filter(function (el) {
            return el[key] !== value;
        });
    }
}
```

so I can have an `Array` of `User`

```
let users:Collection<User> = [];

//add stuff etc ...

//then I can say 
users.remove('name','Jhone Doe');
```

so it remove any items that has a `key` `name` and `value` `Jhone Doe` , but clearly I can't assign the `this` instance , so how would I tackle that?

Comment: or just add Array extension methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434337/how-to-create-an-extension-method-in-typescript-for-date-data-type

Answer (score 0):

First, `remove` won't be found at all unless you declare your array as

```
let users: Collection<User> = [];
```

Second, if you want to remove the elements in place, you need to use `splice`, or do it yourself:

```
remove(key, value) {
    let j = 0;

    for (const el of this) if (el[key] !== value) this[j++] = el;

    this.length = j;
}
```

Even after you've done all this, I wouldn't be surprised if you ran into unexpected behavior, especially as relates to `length`. Subclassing exotic objects such as arrays is still a work in progress.

Comment: -about declaring it as `Array` instead of `Collection` it was a mistake , I edited that, there is no way to gain full access over the `Array` properties ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "gain full access over the `Array` properties"? You do have full access. What you cannot do is swap the object out from under itself. You can't to that with any kind of object.