# What is causing VS to not allow me to extend built-in types with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434337/how-to-create-an-extension-method-in-typescript-for-date-data-type) and other posts like it, and even done exactly what I wanted in the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1#), but in VS I get red underlines and build errors.

[image]
[image]

error txt: 
`Error  TS2339  Build:Property 'contains' does not exist on type 'String'.`

Is there some configuration I'm missing?

### Edit to illustrate comments:

[image]

Comment: Please include code and errors as text, not as images.

Comment: Also, [string already has `includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)...

Comment: I included them as images so that one could **see** the location of the errors. I'll add the text description of them too. Also it looks like my ignorance is showing and should use `includes` for this, but would still like to know the answer.

Comment: there is no `includes` method on string.

Comment: The link in my comment points to the documentation for that method, and has links to the standards where it was defined. TypeScript depends on updated type definitions; perhaps you're using an older version of TypeScript?

Comment: Still, is there an answer to the question being asked? Why can't I extend built-in types as indicated in the linked question?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your first error

> TS2339  Build:Property 'contains' does not exist on type 'String'

make sure to extend the `String` interface in the global scope, not in a module file. That means, there may not be any `export` or `import` at the file top-level.

```
interface String {
    foo(): void
}

String.prototype.foo = () => { console.log("bar") }

"aksljflasd".foo()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=52&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpiqA5sg3gKGSORgHtSAKASgC5kA3U4AE3wF9991MQsA6AA5RSYEQE8BEPmVLIAvMmryAfHmQJSIAM6kANlN2ksFAEQAjOFBNVkHfCbgBrLboBWMXXC3MT08tXwgA)

You could also use `declare global` in a module file:

```
export {}

declare global {
    interface String {
        foo(): void
    }
}

"aksljflasd".foo()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgUBNgGMA2BDKYOAcxwgCM8dEU465RJY4BLAOxmCgDM8siAyjCjtiNehLjcIEABQBKAFxwAbhBbpa9VKhRCRbYgDowUCDHMBPMMCPSIcALxwFTgHyI4WCGwDOEHFsyYlkAIkooUPk4XVC8AGtfHAArbnxfdFC7GQUgA)

Concerning second error

> Property `includes` does not exist on type 'string'

you need minimum `ES6` for `String.prototype.includes`. So it is likely, that you have [`target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) of `ES5` or lower in `tsconfig.json`. Also, when you manually set `lib` option, make sure to have `ES2015.Core` included.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1#code/EQQwNg1gJgZgVuAzrOwB0BLAdgYzAVygFNEAKYAFxIuAEoACAekfqICc2B7NgGnoHcAFkSz0AogGUArPQyJ6FEGwDmRCmiA)

Answer (score 0):

It depends from your project tsconfig file. This is full specification - [tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). Take a closer look at --lib option. Generally in order to have functionalities from different ECMAScript specs it needs to be defined in there.

Take a look on the same issue - [no includes in string](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11890). So looks like compilation needs to have es2016 lib added (or newer spec):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
          // other options
          "lib": [
            "es2019" // any above or equal es2016
          ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted works until you make an **es6** module out of it. Try to use `export` or `import` somewhere in the playground file and watch the errors pop up.

The cleanest solution imho is to move the String interface declaration to a *.d.ts file and include it in the typescript compilation. I put the file into arbitrary /types folder and in my tsconfig.json use `"include": ["types"]` so that it gets picked up. Then you can perform the actual extension `String.prototype.contains = ...` in your code anywhere you like.